# How to serialize a RawQuerySet in Django?

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

I am facing the problem that I need to serialize a RawQuerySet. It doesn't have the values function. I also added a decimal an annotation to every object, which is a count of a field.

Example code:

```
cow_query = """SELECT cow.* (count(leg.id) / 4) as 'percentage' FROM cow JOIN leg ON leg.cow_id = cow.id;"""  
cows = Cow.objects.raw(cow_query)  
json = simplejson.dumps(cows) # this will not work
return HttpRepsonse(json)
```

What is the best way to serialize it.
I want the cow object attributes serialized with the annotation. The simplest is probably just convert everything to dict and lists etc and than call simplejson.dumps, but this will maybe not be the most efficient?

UPDATE:
Just tried to use the http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2 but this will not add the percentage to the json result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `simplejson.dumps([dict(cow.__dict__) for cow in cows])`?  If your `Cow` model only has simple string or integer values this should work, otherwise you'll need to handle your more complex types manually (e.g., `DateTimeField` need to be `unicode`-ed for simplejson).

Comment: This should work, but in the end I went with customizing the dict and using simplejson.dumps to return json. Because I only needed 1 or 2 attributes in the end. This answers the question though, so your answer is accepted.